# IE7: position:absolute doesn't take element out of document flow

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

We're trying to create a page with custom checkboxes by hiding the actual checkbox input element and changing the label's styles with `input:checked+label` CSS selectors. This works fine, but on IE7 the hidden checkbox still takes up space from the document flow, messing up the layout.

Here's an extremely simplified demonstration of the problem:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.hello { position: absolute; left: 200px; }
</style>

<ul>
    <li><div class="hello">Hello</div><div>First</div></li>
    <li><div class="hello">Hello</div><div>Second</div></li>
    <li><div class="hello">Hello</div><div>Third</div></li>
</ul>
```

It seems that any block elements that are taken out of the document flow with `position:absolute` still take up vertical space on IE7.

Here's what it looks like on newer browsers:

```
First         Hello
Second        Hello
Third         Hello
```

On IE7 it looks like this:

```
              Hello
First
              Hello
Second
              Hello
Third
```

For an example that is closer to our actual scenario, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naRUc/3/). Are we missing something? How can we hide the checkbox element so that it still works and takes up no space in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the inputs with this css to hide inputs in ie. (as @Abody97 said)

```
input { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -9999px; 
    left: -9999px; 
    opacity: 0; 
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
}
```

But in order to remove spaces that created by inputs. Remove the spaces between input tags. Like `<input /><input />` not `<input /> <input />`

Answer (score 0):

Try styling your `input` with this set of styles:

```
input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

This seems to work on IE, too.
I hope that helped!

Comment: Sorry, IE7 still reserves space for the `input`s when I tried it on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naRUc/20/

Comment: Be sure that there is no space between at input end tag and new input tag. Be sure `<input /><input />` not `<input /> <input />`.

Comment: @BurakTAMTURK: Removing all whitespace actually fixed this issue. Thanks! Could you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have IE7, so cannot test

But I will just put `display:none`there

```
input { display:none }
```

Comment: On IE7 the checkbox won't function with `display:none`, preventing the use of `:selected`.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja IE does not support `:selected` anyway.

Comment: Ohh, damn IE again. So to just "hide" the input, I will put a `z-index:-1`, `display:block` with `position: absolute`, top left weight height like @Abody97 suggest, whatever works

Comment: @Abody97: It does with selectivizr.

Answer (score 0):

`:checked` is a CSS3 selector and doesn't work in IE7.

<del>Why don't you hide your checkbox with `display:none` instead of moving it with absolute positioning?</del>

You can also hide it with `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: `:checked` works on IE6-8 with selectivizr: http://selectivizr.com/
Also, `visibility:hidden` doesn't remove the element from the document flow even on modern browsers.

Comment: Yep, true. In fact I didn't see any reason to remove it, for me it only have to be invisible. But now I understand the real problem: spaces. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

By just removing the rule `label { display: block; }`, this seemed to work; [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naRUc/25/).

Comment: Unfortunately we need to keep the label as `display: block` because of the extensive styling we need to do in the final layout.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following CSS rule to fix it:

```
label
{
    display: block;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

This enables *hasLayout* behavior in IE7 and makes it render stuff correctly. `*` before rule makes sure this applies only to IE7.
If you need valid CSS 2.1 solution please reply, I'll try to fix it in another way.